# Doctrine: postUpdate is not firing after ManyToMany update from non-empty collection to empty collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have problem with postUpdate event when changing non-empty collection (`user->userRoles`) to empty. During this operation postUpdate event is not firing for User object.

I can't work out why the PostUpdate doesn't fire after ManyToMany update from non-empty collection to empty collection.

Everything is OK when adding from empty to non-empty; same too when adding one, when removing one-of-two, when changing other fields. Just not from non-empty collection to empty collection.

---

```
class DatabaseActivitySubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::postUpdate,
            (...)
        ];
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // This is not called during change from count($user->userRoles)>0 to count($user->userRoles)=0 
    }

}

class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserRole")
     */
    private $userRoles;
    (...other fields...)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know whats been removed from the collection or just when it's empty?

Comment: Clarified content

Comment: I'm tracking entity changes. And everything works fine when User's normal fields are updated, UserRole is added/removed to/from User (and collection is not empty all the time). Only when collection is changing from non-empty to empty - postUpdate event is not called. And I don't know why (maybe it is normal?).